# Elasticsearch COUNT of DISTINCT in GROUP BY

Tags: elasticsearch

There are a few questions similar to this, but not quite the same thing. Feels like I'm diving straight into the deep end with Elastic queries and would appreciate some advice.

This is the SQL, and I can't quite figure out how to query this type of aggregation.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session_id), event_type
FROM events
GROUP BY event_type
```

I'd like to get a count for each event type, but only unique for a given user session.

e.g. Only count the event 'page-view' once for each user session, effectively unique page views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your index mapping defines both the `event_type` and the `session_id` as [`keywords`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type):

```json
PUT /events
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "event_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "session_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you could use the following aggregation query:

```json
POST /events/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.distinct_session_id
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_event_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event_type",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_session_id": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "session_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which'd yield:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_event_type" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "page_view",
          "distinct_session_id" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        }, 
        { 
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that `"size": 10` is a default setting essentially equivalent to SQL's `LIMIT` clause.*

Speaking of SQL, Elasticsearch supports [SQL access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-aggs.html#sql-functions-aggs-count-distinct) too, albeit only within an [X-Pack license](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions). When you have one, you can do:

```json
GET _sql?format=txt
{
  "query": """
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) distnct_sessions, event_type
    FROM events
    GROUP BY event_type
  """
}
```

which'd yield

```sql
distnct_sessions|  event_type   
----------------+---------------
2.0             |page_view      
...
```

Comment: Ah cardinality, that's smart. I had tried a sub agg of term, but didn't think to combine with cardinality. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that cardinality is approximate and looses precision after you hit the count limit defined by `precision_threshold`, which is 3,000 by default and caps out at 40,000. If you're counting anything that requires an exact count, you can't use this, especially when dealing with large numbers. Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html